# stuck with css problem. float/inline issue

Tags: html, css

I am really stuck with this problem.  Page I'm working on is [here](http://cloudninetech.com/newsite/site/homepage.html)

the '`something`' text is part of the "`main`" content.  I want `something` to start from right below the logo...but I can't seem to do this!

Basically I want `content` to be the upper half and then have `main` at the bottom.

I'm not very good at CSS/HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use a doctype
2. [Clear floats](http://work.arounds.org/issue/3/clearing-floats/) either by applying `overflow:hidden` after adding the doctype on `.content` or a clearfix.
3. Optional: add clear:both to the div containing "Something"

Comment: tried adding `overflow:hidden` to `.content` but that makes all the logo and stuff disappear. only thing that shows is "Something"

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--<div id="header">--> 
    <div class="content"> 
         <div id="logo"> 
              <h1><a href="/">Envy Labs</a></h1> 
         </div> 
         <div class="slogan"> 
             <p><em id="tagline">Keeping IT simple</em></p> 
         </div>
         <div class="clear:both"></div><!--Clears Floats-->
    </div> 
<!--</div>--> 
    <div> 
         something
    </div>
```